# New option value not inserting in eav_attribute_option_swatch

Tags: magento2, swatches

i have 700+ text swatch options..
whenever i add new one, it will insert in **eav_attribute_option_value** but the **Admin** value which is supposed to be inserted in **eav_attribute_option_swatch** is not being inserted, instead.. it will just update the last option before the new one.

for example:
[image]

last option is 90 ml and the new option is 1 inch.
after i saved it.. it will look like this
[image]
[image]

**take note** 
its not about the max_input_vars 
this is my setting
max_input_nesting_level 128
max_input_vars 100000
[image]

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this one?

Comment: Have you found solution for this? facing same issue in M2 EE

Answer (score 0):

Run sql query:

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute_option` SET `sort_order`=0 WHERE `attribute_id` = 'Your attribute id';
```

Comment: i applying but not working.